# How to bundle a pre populated database in swift

Tags: sqlite, swift, database-connection

I know there are many related posts but I could notice that none of them explain the way to do it, most says to look the documentation, I looked already but seems to have a  lack of information on bringing a pre populated database to Swift

I have an old database .db with more than 60k lines three columns that I want to bring to my swift SQLite app using FMDB wrapper, the app is working in the iPhone, I tried to just drag the contacts.db to the app but I can not access it. The app when run in the device always start a new database.

I copied the database to the supporting files folder and tried in the app folder as well, could not access from neither

Is there anybody who alredy did that and willing to show me how to do it?

In summary, what I am looking is to insert my contacts.db into the app (bundle) so I can access in the device not in the simulator. I don't need to add delete or edit the contact.db in the device, the database is loaded with all information needed, the user will only for search and be able to display results.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

var databasePath = NSString()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let resourceUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("contacts", withExtension: "db") {
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(resourceUrl.path!) 
    }
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
            .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String

    databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
                    "contacts.db")

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if contactDB == nil {
            println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if contactDB.open() {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
            if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems that this is a really difficult question.... :(

Comment: If I understood correctly: If you want to ship an app with a prepopulated database, then you include the db into the bundle and then copy it out of bundle to the Documents directory to be able to access and modify the DB.

What if I ship an app with a 500 MB prepopulated database? Does it mean my app will actually have two databases inside, 500 MB each? It sounds like a waste of space. Is there a way to optimise it?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 2 Example**

A few assumptions:

1. You have added `libsqlite3.tbd` to your project correctly.
2. You have added an sqlite database to your project correctly.
3. You have copied the required FMDB files to your project correctly.
4. You have a ViewController called `ViewController.swift`

In Xcode open your `ViewController.swift` file and find the following code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

Add the following code below the comment and please remember to change the name of the database in lines 4 & 5.

```
     // Start of Database copy from Bundle to App Document Directory
     let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
     let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
     let destinationSqliteURL = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sqlite.db")
     let sourceSqliteURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("sqlite", withExtension: "db")

     if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationSqliteURL.path!) {
         // var error:NSError? = nil
         do {
             try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(sourceSqliteURL!, toURL: destinationSqliteURL)
             print("Copied")
             print(destinationSqliteURL.path)
         } catch let error as NSError {
             print("Unable to create database \(error.debugDescription)")
         }
     }


     // Let's print the path to the database on your Mac
     // so you can go look for the database in the Finder.
     print(documentsPath)

     let db = FMDatabase(path: destinationSqliteURL.path)

    // Let's open the database
    if !db.open() {
        print("Unable to open database")
        return
    }

    // Let's run some SQL from the FMDB documents to make sure
    // everything is working as expected.  
    if !db.executeUpdate("create table test(x text, y text, z text)", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
        print("create table failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }

    if !db.executeUpdate("insert into test (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["a", "b", "c"]) {
        print("insert 1 table failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }

    if !db.executeUpdate("insert into test (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["e", "f", "g"]) {
        print("insert 2 table failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }

    if let rs = db.executeQuery("select x, y, z from test", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
        while rs.next() {
            let x = rs.stringForColumn("x")
            let y = rs.stringForColumn("y")
            let z = rs.stringForColumn("z")
            print("x = \(x); y = \(y); z = \(z)")
        }
    } else {
        print("select failed: \(db.lastErrorMessage())")
    }

    db.close()
```

You should be able to run the project now and have your database copied.

**Previous answer in case it helps someone**

The [documentation for FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#swift) is pretty helpful on this topic. Using the example there, the code below should work assuming the following things:

1. You are using `Swift 1.2` or later.
2. You have properly added `FMDB` to your project.
3. An SQLite database called `contacts.db` was properly added into the project.
4. In `Build Phases`, then `Link Binary With Libraries` that you have added `libsqlite3.dylib`.

   ```
   //
   //  ViewController.swift
   //

   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
       @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
           let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
           let documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
           let path = documentsFolder.stringByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")
           let database = FMDatabase(path: path)

           if !database.open() {
               println("Unable to open database")
               return
           }

           if !database.executeUpdate("create table test(x text, y text, z text)", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
               println("create table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
           }

           if !database.executeUpdate("insert into test (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["a", "b", "c"]) {
               println("insert 1 table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
           }

           if !database.executeUpdate("insert into test (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)", withArgumentsInArray: ["e", "f", "g"]) {
               println("insert 2 table failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
           }

           if let rs = database.executeQuery("select x, y, z from test", withArgumentsInArray: nil) {
               while rs.next() {
                   let x = rs.stringForColumn("x")
                   let y = rs.stringForColumn("y")
                   let z = rs.stringForColumn("z")
                   println("x = \(x); y = \(y); z = \(z)")
               }
           } else {
               println("select failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
           }

           database.close()

       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }
   }
   ```

To test, just use the `Build and Run` button and you should see  run the simulator and the following results in Xcode's console:

```
x = a; y = b; z = c
x = e; y = f; z = g
```

To show the Console, type Shift + CMD +R or go to View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console

Comment: This shows you getting the database from the DocumentDirectory, but how did you get it from the bundle to the documents directory?

Comment: I just updated my answer @Suragch for Swift 2 and show how to copy the database from the bundle to the documents directory.

Comment: Thanks for making that update. In my particular case, I ended up not needing to copy the database out of the bundle at all because I wasn't writing to it (as discussed in Marcus S. Zarra's answer).

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not Core Data related if you are using FMDB.

Second, it is actually fairly simple.

In Xcode you include the SQL file as a resource that gets loaded into your application when it is built.

Then you locate the file using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file" withExtension:@"sqlite"]`.  From there you proceed with FMDB as normal.

If you want to **write** to that file then you will need to copy it to a writeable location in your application sandbox.

### Update 1

You are locating the file in the bundle but you are not copying it out of the bundle and into the documents directory before attempting to open it.  You need to copy it out of the bundle if it does not currently exist in the documents directory.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I tried and still can not open the edited database in the device. The app open a new database instead, my database is contacts.db is there a problem with this extension? Thanks again :(

Comment: Show some code so we can see what is going on.  Impossible to diagnose without code.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Just edited, the question sorry for the lack of information. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Hi, for copy the file to doc directory is not the following?NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as! String databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent( "contacts.db") –                    I already tried this one from the developer.apple.com:  @NSCopying var resourceURL: NSURL? { get} but I could not make it work.

Comment: No, that does not copy a file.  Please read the documentation.  You need to use the `-[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath: toPath: error:]` method.  That will copy the sqlite file into the location you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Core data you should not use FMDB, use wrapper only for apps using SQLite/database. If you are using Swift it is a good idea to use wrapper if you are not familiar with C++ and databases.